# GAE task are failing in push

Tags: java, google-app-engine, task-queue

I am using GAE task queue to update bulk data in Datastore. Number of records are around 1-2M. To do this I scheduled a cron Job and a queue in this way

```
<queue>
    <name>queueName</name>
    <rate>20/s</rate>
    <bucket-size>300</bucket-size>
    <retry-parameters>
        <task-retry-limit>1</task-retry-limit>
    </retry-parameters>
    <max-concurrent-requests>800</max-concurrent-requests>
</queue>
```

Each task is doing following task

1. Fetching 1500 record from datastore using a cursor.
2. If the next cursor exists create a new task and push in the queue.
3. Process 1500 fetched record, means updating all 1500 in datastore back.

the expected task to add should be around 667, but I can only see 40 tasks in logs.

In logs, I can see the 40 tasks are added in the queue in 40 sec. I m not getting any error in the logs.

Can anybody help me to understand what is happening? Why I m not able to add all the task.

Thanks

Comment: What's your scaling config? How many task queue requests can your running instances can actually process simultaneously?

Comment: Can u specify what does you cron job do?

Comment: The job of cursor is to update records in Datastore in bulk. This cron job run every week.

Comment: @DanCornilescu the scaling the app engine-web.xml has this code ${gae.automaticscaling}.

Answer (score 0):

In your approach the task enqueueing appears to be very tightly coupled with the task request processing, in the sense that the request for one such task in the queue needs to be processed to enqueue the next task. So you need to take a look at your task processing rate limiting factors you may hit. The ones from your queue configuration are pretty generous, but there are others.

If you configured your app with [`threadsafe`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#threadsafe) and if your app design takes advantage of it an instance of your app will be able to handle multiple requests concurrently, up to a maximum depending on its [`max-concurrent-requests` config](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#scaling_elements) and its [processing latency](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime#concurrency_and_latency). Without the `threadsafe` config that maximum is 1.

Once an instance hits the max number of task requests it can process concurrently it won't **start** processing new tasks from the queue (so it won't execute step #1 - enqueueing a new task) until it completes processing at least one of the tasks already in progress. The task enqueueing rate per app instance is thus effectively limited - each running instance can contribute to the overall number of tasks in the queue only with a number equal to the max number of tasks it can process in parallel.

But your app is configured for automatic scaling, so once you manage to quickly "fill up" all your running instances, the scheduler will start new instances for it. As new instances are started they will be able to process more of the tasks in the queue and thus also enqueue new tasks, contributing with the above-mentioned amount to the total number of tasks in the queue.

But this growth in the number of enqueued tasks can be much slower than while instances didn't hit their max processing rate - it takes some time to measure how new instances helps with traffic to determine if more instances are needed or not. The overall growth in the number of tasks in the queue will have a "staircase" profile, with the height of a step being the max number of concurrent requests an instance can handle and the number of steps being the number of new instances started +1.

Since you aren't seeing any actual task enqueuing errors I can only suspect that you're somehow hitting a rate limit in processing your enqueued tasks or somehow that processing completely stops. There can be many reasons for it, including, for example:

- hitting your app's daily budget (most likely due to the number of instance-hours)
- hitting automatic scaling limits

You'd have to investigate your app from this perspective to pinpoint the culprit.

Side note: I assume this is on GAE, not on the development server ([which doesn't respect the task queue configs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/taskqueue/push/using-the-development-server) and most likely can't get even close to GAE's parallel processing capability).